# How can I map a subset of a list of @IndexedEmbedded entities to an additional field?

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

Since the title is a bit confusing, let me illustrate with code:

```
@Indexed @Entity
public class Person {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private Set<Job> jobs = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}

@Entity
public class Job {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Field 
    private Boolean current;
}
```

Now I have two different search scenarios: on properties of the current job(s) of a person and on all jobs the person ever had. I know I can apply a filter after the fact or add another clause to the query, but I'd rather duplicate this information in the index if possible, so I can have two different search queries, say

- `(jobs.id: [10 TO 100])` for all jobs with `id` between 10 and 100
- `(currentJobs.id: [10 TO 100])` for all current jobs with this id range

Is this possible? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a custom bridge for the *Set* list, which iterates the list and just indexes the current job. Check the docs for information and examples for custom bridges.

Comment: I've never done this and my doc-fu is failing me: how would I go about implementing a FieldBridge that indexes a collection of entities, without hard-coding the fields of the entity in the bridge? I've only found examples for FieldBridges that work on a single entity, not @IndexedEmbedded ones.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e4019 - You have to case the object to a set and iterate yourself over the set. Check the DateSplitBridge example. And you are right, you are tying the bridge to your use case and model (unless you would do some reflection magic).

Comment: Ouch, that'll hurt given the depth of the entity tree. I guess I'll have to switch to a query time solution then. Still, accepting as a valid solution.